# CSS: Does it render "ul > li" faster than "ul li"?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

using ">" rather than " " make the rendered faster as I heard from few people?

```
.slide:hover > div > span {
  border-color: #c8c8c8;
}
```

OR

```
.slide:hover div span {
  border-color: #c8c8c8;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

---

**update: *question***

any reliability problem for any of this?

Comment: To be totally serious though, your update question matters much more than the question of performance; see my answer as I pick away at that...

Answer (score 9):

You should very seriously reconsider listening to the people who tell you this type of thing.

The difference is utterly insignificant at *best*. No one should waste time, energy, or brainpower considering such things. This isn't a useful optimization. Don't fall into the trap of premature optimization, especially for a dynamic language like HTML/CSS.

**Write code that is clear, maintainable, and functional *first***, before worrying about anything else.
If `ul > li` looks clearer to you than `ul li`, then write it that way. If not, don't. Keep it simple.

Comment: I'm going to stop wasting my time writing an answer now. It goes into the nitty gritty, so it's simply not worth it. Thanks for filling in for me.

Comment: @Bolt: I don't remember beating you to an answer any other times. You're obviously doing something right; you still have more rep than me!

Comment: (Oh and it's not the deleted answer you see below; it's a different one.)

Comment: I have always been using "ul li" way, it looks clearer for sure, and less char at the file. I was just wondering if I should consider changing the way I do...

Comment: @artmania: Well, the thing is that `li` elements can contain other `ul` elements, so you can actually nest them infinitely. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 3):

`.slide:hover > div > span` *is* more efficient than `.slide:hover div span`.

However, you're **never** going to notice the difference with average size pages.

If you used the Child Selector instead of the Descendant Selector everywhere in your stylesheet for a *really freaking massive/complex* page, you could shave off a noticeable portion of the render time (see comment by @Boris Zbarsky).
With average size pages, you might shave off *a few milliseconds*.

There is one disadvantage to using the Child Selector - IE6 does not support it.

For 99% of sites, IE6 support is not an issue, but some people still do use it:

http://ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Of course, adding a `<` symbol and an extra space also adds two more characters, which could "bloat" the size of your CSS file and "increase" loading times. Clearly a tradeoff.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Don't worry about that, you could write `div>span` to save bloating up the CSS with spaces :)

Comment: It really depends on your markup.  I've seen pages that can save a second or two off render time (25% of the total in their case) by using `>` instead of space in selectors.

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky: I'll take your word for it. I've changed my answer slightly.

Comment: @Cody Gray: honestly, you should worry more about your images bloating a web page before anything else. 1 character = 8bits, but a poorly compressed JPG or PNG image can be 150kb+ of unwanted data bloat.

Answer (score 2):

> Which is faster?

Like Cody and thirtydot said, theoretically using `>` should be faster, but even styling for IE6 is less a waste of your time than styling for performance. Browsers are *fast enough*; trust your *browsers*, not the *people* who tell you this, especially not those who don't provide any *browser* benchmarks to back their claims.

> any reliability problem for any of this?

Sure. Besides IE6 not supporting `>` at all as thirtydot mentions, there's also the difference in elements matched since `>` and the whitespace combinators select different things:

```
<section class="slide">
  <div>
    <span></span>   <!-- [1] -->
    <div>
      <span></span> <!-- [2] -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span></span> <!-- [3] -->
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

What's selected and what's not:

1. **Selected by both selectors**
   This `span` is a child of a `div` which is a child of an element with class `slide`. Since `span` is a child of `div`, it's also a descendant of `div`. Likewise for `div` and its `.slide` parent/ancestor.

   On hovering the `.slide` element, this `span` is selected. The rule applied is the second one because both selectors are of equal specificity, but the second one, well, comes second.
2. **Selected only by `.slide:hover div span`**
   This `span` is in a `div`, *but* its parent `div` is located in *another* `div` that doesn't have the class `slide`. So the first selector doesn't find this element.

   The inner parent `div` is, however, a grandchild of a `.slide` element. Regardless of depth, it's still in some way a descendant of `.slide` (it's contained somewhere within it).

   On hovering the `.slide` element, this `span` is selected. The rule applied is the second one because it's the only one that matches.
3. **Selected only by `.slide:hover div span`**
   This `span`'s parent is a `p` element, not a `div`. Easy enough; the first selector doesn't find this element.

   The `span` is, however, a grandchild of a `div` element, which itself is inside a `.slide`.

   On hovering the `.slide` element, this `span` is selected. The rule applied is the second one because it's the only one that matches.

One last thing: in all three scenarios do you find that the rules in only the second selector are applied. **This is purely coincidental**; the differences in how supporting browsers look for elements to match are still real.

Comment: See. You know *way* more about CSS than I do. I'm a .NET/C++ developer that's just pretending. I still think my argument to thirtydot's post that using `<` and an extra space will "bloat" the code with more characters, also increasing loading time, is pretty good. Google worries about this sort of thing, so why shouldn't everyone? :-p

Comment: @Cody Gray: Well thanks. I just wasn't sure if it was worth the details for such a simple question - whether I was answering the right one anyway. I still believe you hit the nail right on the head, and deserve all 5 votes... after all, like Sayem said, KISS!

Comment: The thing is... the browser CSS engine developers are the ones who tell you to use `>` instead of space.  But yes, for most uses it doesn't matter.  It starts to matter once you have lots of rules, lots of elements, or lots of dynamic changes (or any combination of those).  For example, loading the HTML5 single-page spec the selector matching is something like 25% of the load time, and a lot of that is due to its use of space in selectors.