# Do additional, unused CSS definitions slow down browsers?

Tags: css, version-control, onload, slowdown

After working with many CMSes and cutting up many HTML designs, when I saw [SilverStripe's use of CSS](http://silverstripe.com/), I was converted.

Essentially, that it would be a waste to change IDs in `<div>` tags depending upon the page you were on, and that changing the `<body>` tag's classes and ID would be an easier way of changing specific pages.

Such convictions were brought into question by a coworker during the following problem:

On a specific website, we have a variety of pages that are similar in structure.  Some may include a special form, and some may not.  All special forms should have a different background image depending upon the sub-section we are in.

Due to a claim that "additional lines of CSS slow down `body.onLoad`s," my argument to code all background expectations in the CSS was rejected.

Can anybody cite evidence between a variety of cases?  Cases including: Badly-coded CSS, and CSS well-coded, but having a variety of unused CSS on each page?

> (And specifically speaking on my problem, can anybody explain my unease?  I feel uncomfortable assuming images will be there and auto-generating Inline CSS (or header-section-based style tags) based upon a variable from a database.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not going to matter (*noticeably*) unless your website is Gmail or YouTube (or is similarly CSS heavy).

Google has some recommendations in their Page Speed guide:

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#RemoveUnusedCSS

> Removing or deferring style rules that
>   are not used by a document avoid
>   downloads unnecessary bytes and allow
>   the browser to start rendering sooner.
>
> Before a browser can begin to render a
>   web page, it must download and parse
>   any stylesheets that are required to
>   lay out the page. Even if a stylesheet
>   is in an external file that is cached,
>   rendering is blocked until the browser
>   loads the stylesheet from disk. In
>   addition, once the stylesheet is
>   loaded, the browser's CSS engine has
>   to evaluate every rule contained in
>   the file to see if the rule applies to
>   the current page. Often, many web
>   sites reuse the same external CSS file
>   for all of their pages, even if many
>   of the rules defined in it don't apply
>   to the current page.
>
> The best way to
>   minimize the latency caused by
>   stylesheet loading and rendering time
>   is to cut down on the CSS footprint;
>   an obvious way to do this is to remove
>   or defer CSS rules that aren't
>   actually used by the current page.

Concerning this:

> Due to a claim that "additional lines
>   of CSS slow down body.onLoads," my
>   argument to code all background
>   expectations in the CSS was rejected.

The extra time is in the order of a few milliseconds. Do what is easier and maintainable, not what is more "efficient".

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer, Thirty.  Since we're not CSS-Heavy, I feel a bit more relieved.  Now to see if I can get through politics..

Comment: Thanks for the accept, though it does feel a little premature. Note that by "CSS heavy", I mean a [200KB stylesheet](http://s.ytimg.com/yt/cssbin/www-core-vflJFxATE.css) (that's after being minified!) like Youtube has.

Comment: Also worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674395/css-does-it-render-ul-li-faster-than-ul-li - I should have used the phrase "premature optimization" in my own answer :)